# How do I update my Ruby version if I have multiple versions installed?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I managed to use rvm (Ruby Version Manageer) to update to the latest Ruby version (ruby-1.9.2-p180). To do this I ran the following commands:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p180
rvm ruby-1.9.2-p180
ruby -v
```

The output of that last command indicates that it is successfully installed:

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
```

Running a "which ruby" command indicates that I'm using the correct Ruby version as well:

```
/Users/Bijan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
```

So in the current Terminal session, the new Ruby is installed properly. However, whenever I open a new Terminal session, it defaults me back to the original version I was running:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]
which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

So, in other words, I seem to have to different versions properly installed, but the default is going to the /usr/local/bin instead of the RVM installation. How do I go about making sure that the default Ruby version that I am using is the most recent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your default ruby version to be the latest with the following:

```
rvm --default use <ruby version here>
```

By default, the `system` ruby is your default in RVM

Answer (score 0):

create a **.rvmrc** file under the directory (~/ in your case) which includes the following:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p180
```

save it and you are good to go.